# Python coverage report vs time with Bamboo

Tags: bamboo, coverage.py

My project is using Bamboo as our CI server. We have just started using coverage.py track our unit test coverage (64%! w00t!). I'm wondering if there is a way to plot our test coverage vs build #? I hoping to create a plot that shows it gradually moving towards 100% over the next few months.

Basically, we have the overall coverage # that comes out of coverage.py; that's easy enough to get. Is there a way to make a custom graph/report in Bamboo?

(Alternatively, should we give up the ghost and switch to Jenkins if it supports it?)